# How to use branches in GitHub for Windows

Tags: github, github-for-windows

I've just started using "GitHub for Windows", and I can't figure out how to see other branches (or create other branches).

The [help page](http://windows.github.com/help.html) mentions this feature, and even shows a screenshot, but does not detail how to get to it.

I am aware of how to create and checkout branches from the command line, but I would like to do this from within the UI.

Does anyone know how to do this?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Found it! It's actually very easy when you realise where to look. The name of your branch is shown next to the "sync" or "push to github" button. Clicking on this shows all the existing branches, as well as a text box to create a new one:

[image]